# Django sum of product query on joined table

Tags: django, django-models

In a nutshell I wish to know how to express the following SQL query in Django

```
SELECT SUM(product.cost_price * product.markup_percentage) from product 
INNER JOIN shopping_cart on shopping_cart.product_id = product.id 
WHERE shopping_cart.user_id = <user_id>;
```

There is a ShoppingCart model which has a FK to Product model. I am trying to fetch the total amount to be paid by user for all the product in their shopping cart.

At present adding another column to the `product` table is not an option.

I know that I can just do

```
shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.objects.select_related('product').filter(user_id=<user_id>)
```

to retrieve the list of products and perform the sum of product operation in python code.

The answer suggested in [Sumproduct using Django's aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541864/sumproduct-using-djangos-aggregation) does not work as mentioned in the comment to the answer.

So other than writing a raw SQL query or doing the calculation in python is there any other way to do this in Django?

Comment: Not with your data structure. I'd personally recommend doing it in Python, e.g. `sum(cart.products.values_list('price', flat=True))`.

Comment: Yes @AntonStrogonoff I am currently using a sum([t[0] * t[1] for t in product_queryset]) in python to accomplish this. I didn't know about the values_list function before. Thanks for introducing me to that. That can make my code a little bit more elegant. I was wondering if there is any efficient way to handle this case in Django.

Answer (score 0):

Does that other answer work if you change it to this?

```
.extra(
    select={'actual_price': 'SUM(cost_price * markup_percentage)'},
).aggregate(total=Sum('actual_price'))['total']
```

Comment: No it doesn't. The problem here is that aggregate can only work on actual table fields not on computed properties.